# Drupal - user registration form- theming

Tags: 7, theming

I need to do theming of user registration form

I m doing in this way

Module file

```
  function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      $form['#theme'] = 'user_register';
    }
```

Template file

```
function mytheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'user_register' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-register',
    ),
  );
}

function mytheme_preprocess_user_register(&$variables) {
  $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render_children($variables['form']);
}
```

And then I added user-register.tpl.php with my desired markup, a

```
<?php echo $rendered; ?>
```

Which is working fine . Now problem is that i need to rearrnage order of all fileds

Currently i have following

username, email and password, firstname , last name

I need sequence like username , firstname, email, lastname, password

can anybody tell me how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip your preprocess function and render directly in your template file like this:

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['user_register']['username']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['user_register']['firstname']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['user_register']['email']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['user_register']['lastname']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render($form['user_register']['password']); ?>
```

Wrap these lines of code inside HTML if you want to. Use `<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>` to render automatically the rest of the fields you haven't rendered yet.

EDIT:

An example:

```
<div id="username">
  <?php print drupal_render($form['user_register']['username']); ?>
</div>
<div id="firstname">
  <?php print drupal_render($form['user_register']['firstname']); ?>
</div>
[...]
```

Comment: what about form submissions, how it will work then

Comment: Don't modify anything of what you've done. Just skip your `mytheme_preprocess_user_register` function and work directly in your `user-register.tpl.php` file using the syntax I showed you.

Comment: yes, i did i smae. it is showing all fields

Comment: You can rearrange them in the order you want, in the HTML tags you want. I'll make an edit in my post to illustrate with an example.

Comment: yes i did, but why it is displaying all fields. even i didnt add <?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>

Comment: i have <?php print drupal_render($form['user_register']['email']); ?>
 in my tpl only

Comment: You deleted the preprocess function?

Comment: Yes, i deleted already  template file is having function bootstap_subtheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'user_register' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-register',
    ),
  );
}

Comment: yes, i clear cache twice

Comment: Could you replace the `'template' => ...` line by `'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourtheme') . '/templates/user-register'` ?

Comment: Can u tell  me how to print out all fields. May be this is not exact

Comment: To print out all fields in your `user-register.tpl.php`, use `<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
`

Comment: sorry, i mean in array format. as may be some array issue

Comment: Just wrap all your fields in <table> tags and you'll be good. I'm not going to write down all the code for you. Have a look  at this article about theming forms https://www.drupal.org/node/1200216

Comment: ok,  one thing i am not getting submit button

Answer (score 0):

Look at [poll module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21poll%21poll.module/function/template_preprocess_poll_vote/7) for a good example of this.

You can simply (with item being something in your form);

```
$form = $variables['form'];
$variables['item'] = drupal_render($form['item']);
$variables['rendered'] = drupal_render_children($form);
```

However there are other ways of achieving this and keeping the rearranging within the UI (*/admin/config/people/accounts/fields* etc) by using `hook_field_extra_fields` - [poll module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21poll%21poll.module/function/poll_field_extra_fields/7) does this as well I've noticed.  It can be used for adding existing base fields which don't otherwise show in the Manage Display UI (like node author, created, updated times, etc) - here's an example for [user picture](http://foggyperspective.com/article/positioning-users-profile-picture-manage-display-screen).

Comment: Do like this <?php print drupal_render($form['account']['pass']['pass1']);?>

Comment: Can you pleaase explain it more. I am not able to make it working